# Exporting .csv after groupby pandas function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I`m starting my studies in python and pandas and, at the moment, I`m trying to create a project that I need to export in .csv the following

I created a groupby function like this one below:

```
df2 = result.groupby(['Sub ID','Date','Campaign Name','Source',]).agg({'Clicks': 'sum', 'Conversions': 'sum', 'Views': 'sum', 'Cost': 'sum', 'Net Profit': 'sum', 'Revenue': 'sum', 'Profit': 'sum'})
```

However, when I export to .csv only the columns for Clicks, Conversions, Views, Cost, Net Profit, Revenue and Profit are exported and not the first ones. Does anybody know how to fix that?

Thank you

Comment: Can you include the code you use to write to csv?

Comment: `df2 = result.groupby(['Sub ID','Date','Campaign Name','Source',],as_index=False).agg({'Clicks': 'sum', 'Conversions': 'sum', 'Views': 'sum', 'Cost': 'sum', 'Net Profit': 'sum', 'Revenue': 'sum', 'Profit': 'sum'})` and the use `to_csv` .. ?

Comment: I assume you are using `ignore_index=True` when you export, just set it to `False` or don't include it.

Comment: Yes, I was using the index= True. I changed to false and it worked. 
Now is like this: df2.to_csv("df2.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

Answer (score 1):

Your aggregations can be done in a cleaner way. This should solve your problem:

```
target_cols = ['Clicks', 'Conversions', 'Views', 'Cost', 'Net Profit', 'Revenue', 'Profit']
df2 = result.groupby(['Sub ID','Date','Campaign Name','Source',])[target_cols].sum()
df.to_csv(desired_path)
```

Comment: think you meant `sum`?

Comment: Thank you that looks much easier and cleaner

Comment: No prob. Please upvote/accept if this answers your question.